# How to compare text on 2 column in excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

I have 2 coloumn, A and B

coloumn A has 500 data of student's name and column B has 800 data of student's name.

example:

```
      A                  B
    ================ |============
    Anwar F          | Aliando munawaf
    Budi Sujatmiko   | Syaiful anhar
    Dudung S         | Syifa
    Aliando munawaf  | anwar F
    Amir Rudin       | Amir Rudin
                     | Dudung
```

I want to compare A to B. if data in column A is not found in colomn B the it printed in colomn C.

```
  =========================================================
     A                  B                    C
    ================ |====================|===============
    Anwar F          | Aliando munawaf    | Budi Sujatmiko
    Budi Sujatmiko   | Syaiful anhar      | Catlea
    Dudung S         | Syifa              |
    Aliando munawaf  | anwar Fuadi        |
    Amir Rudin       | Amir Rudin         |
    Catlea           | Dudung             |
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

In cell C2, enter this array formula. It must be confirmed with Control-Shift-Enter.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$9999,MATCH(,IFERROR(MATCH(A$2:A$9999,B$2:B$9999,),COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$2:A$9999)),)),"")
```

Now copy it. Select C3 and downward as far as you like, then paste.

Comment: @azalika Were you able to get this going? It works. I have tested it. If you need help please email me the file. My email address is daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula *(enter in `C2` then copy till the last record)*

```
=IF(EXACT($A2,""),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A:$A,$B:$B,0)),$A:$A,""))
```

Be aware that the missing records are:

```
Anwar F
Budi Sujatmiko
Dudung S
Catlea
```

as there is not exact match for

```
Anwar F
Dudung S
```

Comment: so the name must be exact ?
but I have a different data. like in coloumn A has Dudung S but in coloumn B has Dudung Supratman. it's same person.
btw, I has tried your formula, but it shows"the formula you typed containt an error". I use 2007 btw.

Comment: Do you use `;` as separators?

Comment: Long time I migrated to Excel 2103, but I believe this formula will work in 2007: `=IF(EXACT($A1,""),"",IF(ISNA(MATCH($A:$A,$B:$B,0)),$A:$A,""))` Do let me know if it works so I will update the answer.

Comment: As regards the exact match of the name, how would you know that this Dudung S. is Dudung Supratman and not Dudung Susanto. _Mana yang begitu?_